# Symfony Alice Bundle

Tags: symfony, alice-fixtures

Hi I'm using Alice Bundle in my Symfony2 project.

I would like to have an auto increment for my position property.

But I don't find the right syntax.

```
FM\AppBundle\Entity\Faq\Question:
    FaqQuestion_{1..100}:
        headline: <sentence()>
        body: <sentence()>
        position: <autoincrement()> #Does not work
        category: @FaqCategory*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `current()` ?

```
FM\AppBundle\Entity\Faq\Question:
FaqQuestion_{1..100}:
    headline: <sentence()>
    body: <sentence()>
    position: <current()>
    category: @FaqCategory*
```